# Can't access Linux server via SSH

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, terminal

I have a MacBook Air, version 10.12.1 (Sierra).
I have been thus far with Windows for the better part of the last 20 years and few days ago I switched to Mac for the first time.

I have a shared hosting account with some company that grants me SSH access as well. In Windows, I simply use Putty, and it works fine, but on Mac, whether I try Terminal or some other app that I installed (MacTerm), whenever I try to connect I get

```
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused
```

I have been trying to research the issue on Google and StackOverFlow for the past few days, and didn't come up with any solution. Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

One other thing - in one of the related posts I found a suggestion to use a command that can help understand perhaps what's going wrong, I'll post it here:

```
MacBook-Air:~ user$ ssh -vvv xx.xx.xx.xx
OpenSSH_7.2p2, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "xx.xx.xx.xx" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused
```

Edit: I managed to connect to the server, using -p and a different port which was the correct one, but now when I enter the password the access is denied, and I have the correct password 100% - what could it be?

Thanks

Comment: "Edit: I managed to connect to the server, using -p and a different port which was the correct one, but now when I enter the password the access is denied, and I have the correct password 100% - what could it be?" - Any number of things. Post the verbose (`-vvv`) output again.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to connect ssh server from terminal please please follow the rules

```
$ ssh username@ip
```

Example: If you try to login as root in ssh server

```
$ ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

If you not mention user name when you ssh, it means you try to connect your ssh server as the client logged in user. Please try to login as ssh server login user.

Answer (score 0):

"Connection Refused" means that

- The server isn't listening on the port you're connecting to
- The server is too busy
- Your connection was explicitly rejected by a firewall

It's unlikely that the server is not listening or is busy, so either you're trying to connect to the wrong host or you're firewalled.

Comment: Or you have handed bad credentials.

Comment: @user657451: You won't get a "Connection Refused" if you pass the wrong credentials. You'll see "Permission denied".

Comment: True but his last comment was "acccess is denied" - not specifying what message got thrown back, which is why I asked him to post the error he was *now* getting